Is it possible to write HQL with with clause
how to write the With clause in HQL. Example below query.
WITH dept_count AS (
SELECT deptno, COUNT(*) AS dept_count
FROM   emp
GROUP BY deptno)
SELECT e.ename AS employee_name,
dc.dept_count AS emp_dept_count
FROM   emp e,
dept_count dc
WHERE  e.deptno = dc.deptno;
Hello please let me know is it possible to write query with with clause in HQL.
WITH dept_count AS (
SELECT deptno, COUNT(*) AS dept_count
FROM   emp
GROUP BY deptno)
SELECT e.ename AS employee_name,
dc.dept_count AS emp_dept_count
FROM   emp e,
dept_count dc
WHERE  e.deptno = dc.deptno;
